# Why does bounded distortion imply the following inequality?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, discrete-dynamical-systems

Let $f: I \to I$ be a one-dimensional differentiable function of bounded distortion with distortion constant $M$, where $I$ is a compact interval in $\mathbb{R}$. That is, $I$ can be partitioned such that for each $J$ in the partition there exists an interger $n_J$ such
\begin{align}
\max_{x, y \in J} \log \frac{Df^k(x)}{Df^k(y)} \leq M, \quad 1 \leq k \leq n_J.
\end{align}
I've been told that this implies for any subintervals $A, B \subset I$
\begin{align}
 \frac{|A|}{|B|} \leq e^M \frac{|f(A)|}{|f(B)|}
\end{align}
where $|A|$ denotes the size of the interval $A$. The problem is that I don't know how to go about showing this true, does anyone know how to show this?

Comment: Although I think I can guess what all the symbols mean, could you be more explicit about the domain and range of $f$, what $k$ is in the first equation, what $A$ and $B$ are in the second equation, and what is $|A|$?

Comment: It looks as if you can simplify the left hand-side of the first inequality by cancelling $D$ in the numerator and the denominator =).

Comment: Luc Guyot: apologies, the $Df^k$ is meant to mean the derivative of the $k$-th iterate of $f$. I've changed the constant to $M$ to make that clearer.

Comment: I think it should be $e^M$ in the second inequality?

Comment: Anthony Quas: Yes you're right, I'll change that now

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I found the solution, it's just the mean value theorem.

By the mean value theorem we know that there exist points $\eta_1, \eta_2$ such that
\begin{align}
Df(\eta_1) = \frac{|f(A)|}{|A|}, \quad Df(\eta_2) = \frac{|f(B)|}{|B|}
\end{align}
Thus we have
\begin{align}
\frac{|f(B)|}{|B|} \Big/ \frac{|f(A)|}{|A|} = \frac{|Df(\eta_2)|}{|Df(\eta_1)|} \leq e^M,
\end{align}
which rearranges to
\begin{align}
\frac{|A|}{|B|} \leq e^M \frac{|f(A)|}{|f(B)|}.\end{align}